# How to disable symfony2 http cache globally?

Tags: php, symfony, http-caching

I'm developing website with `Symfony2`.

Most of pages of the website are highly dynamic and because of that I have problems with HTTP cache.

I found out that if I use function `setMaxAge(0)` for response, problems would be fixed, but it's not possible now to set it for each response.
Is there any way to disable HTTP cache or  `setMaxAge` to 0 globally?

Comment: You normally disable the cache within your browser. There are extensions for webdevelopers depending on which browser you use. Otherwise you can override / remove headers within the webserver configuration. That's true "globally"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added this line to construct of `Response` class:

```
$this->setExpires(new \DateTime('1980-01-01'));
```

I don't think this is such a good idea, but it works!

Comment: You should probably do this in a "before" filter of a base controller, and not in Symfony source code.